# Gaussian is a rapidly decreasing function.

Tags: fourier-analysis

Definition of rapidly decreasing function

$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} |x|^k |f^{(l)}(x)| < \infty$$ for every $k,l\ge 0$.

Given the Gaussian function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$, I know that its derivatives will always be in form of $P(x)e^{-x^2}$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree, say, $n$. Then $|x|^k |f^{(l)}(x)|$ will be $Q(x) e^{-x^2}$ where $Q(x)$ is of degree $n+k$. $e^{-x^2}$ is bounded apparently. But how could I "immediately" argue this whole thing is bounded?

Comment: I guess that you never proved that $x e^{-x} \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$ because the proof is exactly the same here

Answer (score 1):

Suppose
$(e^{-x^2})^{(n)}
=p_n(x) e^{-x^2}
$.
Then

$\begin{array}\\
(e^{-x^2})^{(n+1)}
&=(p_n(x) e^{-x^2})'\\
&=p_n'(x) e^{-x^2}-p_n(x)(2x) e^{-x^2}\\
&=e^{-x^2}(p_n'(x) -2xp_n(x))\\
\end{array}
$

so if we define
$p_0(x) = 1$
and
$p_{n+1}(x)
=p_n'(x) -2xp_n(x)
$,
then
$(e^{-x^2})^{(n)}
=p_n(x) e^{-x^2}
$.

Looking at this recurrence,
we see that
$p_n(x)$
is a polynomial
of degree $n$
with leading coefficient
$(-2)^n$.

We could derive a recurrence
for the coefficients,
but this is enough
to show that
$|p_n(x)|
\le C_n x^n
$
for $x \ge 1$,
where
$C_n$ is the sum of the
absolute value of
the coefficients of
$p_n(x)$.

Since
$x^ne^{-x^2} \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$,
$p_n(x)e^{-x^2} \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$.

Easy proof
that
$x^ne^{-x^2} \to 0$
as $x \to \infty$:

From the power series,
$e^{x^2}
\gt \dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}
$
so
$x^n e^{-x^2}
< n! x^{-n}
\to 0
$
as
$x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

An exponential always beats a polynomial in the end...

$|x| \le e^{|x|}$ so $|x|^n < e^{n |x|} < e^{x^2}$ if $|x| > n$, therefore $\left|x^n e^{-x^2}\right| < 1$ there.

Since the continuous function $x^n e^{-x^2}$ is also
bounded on  the finite interval $[-n,n]$, we conclude that $x^n e^{-x^2}$ is bounded on $\mathbb R$.

Take a linear combination of 
those and you have your $Q(x) e^{-x^2}$.